# Altenative to max-height 0% for folding elements

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a table like in this mockup: https://jsfiddle.net/sungi/3L4nw2hj/12/
It's programatically created based on external data, so I can't tell how many elements there will be in each row.

I have problem with

`<div class="inv_fields">` and `<div class="doc_line">`

When i set max-height value to 0rem and 100rem (as value which theoretically shouldn't be reached) it doesn't take doc_line space, but transitions are a bit off  - almost instant slide in and slight delay when hiding as it goes up to 100rem and down.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
            #grid {
                display: grid;

                & #header {
                    flex-direction: row;
                    font-weight: bold;
                    font-size: 1.5rem;
                    border-bottom: 1px solid;

                    & div {
                        width:25%;
                    }
                }           
            }

            .row {
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
                grid-column-start:  span 4;
                justify-content: center;
                max-height: 100%;

                .l1 {
                    display: flex;
                    flex-direction: row;
                    padding-left: 0.25rem 0rem 0.25rem 1rem;
                    cursor: pointer;

                    &:hover{
                        background-color: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.267);
                    }

                    & div {
                        width: 25%;
                    }
                }

                & .l2 {
                    width: 98%;
                    display: flex;
                    overflow: hidden;
                    align-self: center;
                    max-height: 100rem;
                    transition: all 1s ease-out;

                    &.folded {
                        max-height: 0rem;
                    }

                    & .doc_header {
                        font-weight: bold;
                    }

                    & .doc_header, .doc_line {
                        display: inherit;

                        &:hover:not(.doc_header, :has(inv_fields:hover)) {
                            background-color: rgba(172, 26, 26, 0.267);
                        }
                    }
                }

                & .inv_fields {
                    width: 98%;
                    flex-basis: 100%;
                    overflow: hidden;
                    align-self: flex-end;
                    flex-direction: column;
                    border: 1px solid;
                    max-height: 100rem;
                    transition: all 1s;

                    &.folded {
                        max-height: 0rem;                        
                    }

                    & .header {
                        display: flex;
                        flex-direction: row;
                        font-weight: bold;
                        width: 100%;

                        & div {
                            flex: 1 0 25%;
                        }
                    }

                    & .inv_line {
                        width: 100%;
                        border-bottom: 1px solid;
                        cursor: pointer;

                        & .inv_main {
                            display: flex;
                            flex-direction: row;
                            width: 100%;

                            &:hover {
                                background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.199);
                            }

                            & div {
                                flex: 1 0 25%;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            .doc_fields {
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
                width: 100%;

                & div > div {
                    width: 25%;
                }

                & .doc_line {
                    width: 100%;
                    flex-wrap: wrap;
                    cursor: pointer;
                }
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="grid">
            <div id="header" class="row">
                <div class="id">ID</div>
                <div class="name">NAME</div>
                <div class="status">STATUS</div>
                <div class="doc_count">COUNT</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="l1">
                    <div class="id">001</div>
                    <div class="name">xyz</div>
                    <div class="status">active</div>
                    <div class="doc_count">3</div>    
                </div>
                <div class="l2 folded">
                    <div class="doc_fields">
                        <div class="doc_header">
                            <div class="doc_number">DOC NUMBER</div>
                            <div class="supplier_id">SUPPLIER ID</div>
                            <div class="supplier_name">SUPPLIER NAME</div>
                            <div class="inv_count">INVOICE COUNT</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="doc_line">
                            <div class="doc_number">00000000</div>
                            <div class="supplier_id">0123456789</div>
                            <div class="supplier_name">XYZ XYZ</div>
                            <div class="inv_count">3</div>
                            <div class="inv_fields folded">
                                <div class="inv_main header">
                                    <div class="inv_id">INV_ID</div>
                                    <div class="inv_amount">INV AMOUNT</div>
                                    <div class="inv_curr">CURR</div>
                                    <div class="inv_amount_usd"></div>
                                    <div class="inv_owner"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="inv_line">
                                    <div class="inv_main">
                                        <div>000000001</div>
                                        <div>1000</div>
                                        <div>USD</div>
                                        <div>1000</div>
                                        <div>xyz</div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="inv_details folded">sth</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="inv_line">
                                    <div class="inv_main">
                                        <div>000000001</div>
                                        <div>1000</div>
                                        <div>USD</div>
                                        <div>1000</div>
                                        <div>xyz</div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="inv_details folded">sth</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="inv_line">
                                    <div class="inv_main">
                                        <div>000000002</div>
                                        <div>1000</div>
                                        <div>USD</div>
                                        <div>1000</div>
                                        <div>xyz</div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="inv_details folded">sth</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="inv_line">
                                    <div class="inv_main">
                                        <div>000000003</div>
                                        <div>1000</div>
                                        <div>USD</div>
                                        <div>1000</div>
                                        <div>xyz</div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="inv_details folded">sth</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="inv_line">
                                    <div class="inv_main">
                                        <div>000000004</div>
                                        <div>1000</div>
                                        <div>USD</div>
                                        <div>1000</div>
                                        <div>xyz</div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="inv_details folded">sth</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="l1">
                    <div class="id">002</div>
                    <div class="name">jkl</div>
                    <div class="status">active</div>
                    <div class="doc_count">3</div>    
                </div>
                <div class="l2 folded">
                    <div class="doc_fields">
                        <div class="doc_header">
                            <div class="doc_number">DOC NUMBER</div>
                            <div class="supplier_id">SUPPLIER ID</div>
                            <div class="supplier_name">SUPPLIER NAME</div>
                            <div class="inv_count">INVOICE COUNT</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="doc_line">
                            <div class="doc_number">00000000</div>
                            <div class="supplier_id">0123456789</div>
                            <div class="supplier_name">JKL JKL</div>
                            <div class="inv_count">3</div>
                            <div class="inv_fields folded">
                                <div class="inv_main header">
                                    <div class="inv_id">INV_ID</div>
                                    <div class="inv_amount">INV AMOUNT</div>
                                    <div class="inv_curr">CURR</div>
                                    <div class="inv_amount_usd"></div>
                                    <div class="inv_owner"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="inv_line">
                                    <div class="inv_main">
                                        <div>000000002</div>
                                        <div>2000</div>
                                        <div>USD</div>
                                        <div>2000</div>
                                        <div>jkl</div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="inv_details folded"></div>
                                </div>
                                
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
            $('.l1').on("click", (event) => {
                console.log($(event.target).parent().parent().find('.l2').toggleClass('folded'));
            })

            $('.doc_line').click(() => {
                console.log($(event.target).parent().find('.inv_fields').toggleClass('folded'));
                
            })
        </script>           
    </body>
</HTML>
```

I tried to swap max-height values to % and it helped with transitions timing, but then inv_fields takes space of doc_line even if it's folded.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
            #grid {
                display: grid;

                & #header {
                    flex-direction: row;
                    font-weight: bold;
                    font-size: 1.5rem;
                    border-bottom: 1px solid;

                    & div {
                        width:25%;
                    }
                }           
            }

            .row {
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
                grid-column-start:  span 4;
                justify-content: center;
                max-height: 100%;

                .l1 {
                    display: flex;
                    flex-direction: row;
                    padding-left: 0.25rem 0rem 0.25rem 1rem;
                    cursor: pointer;

                    &:hover{
                        background-color: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.267);
                    }

                    & div {
                        width: 25%;
                    }
                }

                & .l2 {
                    width: 98%;
                    display: flex;
                    overflow: hidden;
                    align-self: center;
                    max-height: 100%;
                    transition: all 1s ease-out;

                    &.folded {
                        max-height: 0%;
                    }

                    & .doc_header {
                        font-weight: bold;
                    }

                    & .doc_header, .doc_line {
                        display: inherit;

                        &:hover:not(.doc_header, :has(inv_fields:hover)) {
                            background-color: rgba(172, 26, 26, 0.267);
                        }
                    }
                }

                & .inv_fields {
                    width: 98%;
                    flex-basis: 100%;
                    overflow: hidden;
                    align-self: flex-end;
                    flex-direction: column;
                    border: 1px solid;
                    max-height: 100%;
                    transition: all 1s;

                    &.folded {
                        max-height: 0%;                        
                    }

                    & .header {
                        display: flex;
                        flex-direction: row;
                        font-weight: bold;
                        width: 100%;

                        & div {
                            flex: 1 0 25%;
                        }
                    }

                    & .inv_line {
                        width: 100%;
                        border-bottom: 1px solid;
                        cursor: pointer;

                        & .inv_main {
                            display: flex;
                            flex-direction: row;
                            width: 100%;

                            &:hover {
                                background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.199);
                            }

                            & div {
                                flex: 1 0 25%;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            .doc_fields {
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
                width: 100%;

                & div > div {
                    width: 25%;
                }

                & .doc_line {
                    width: 100%;
                    flex-wrap: wrap;
                    cursor: pointer;
                }
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="grid">
            <div id="header" class="row">
                <div class="id">ID</div>
                <div class="name">NAME</div>
                <div class="status">STATUS</div>
                <div class="doc_count">COUNT</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="l1">
                    <div class="id">001</div>
                    <div class="name">xyz</div>
                    <div class="status">active</div>
                    <div class="doc_count">3</div>    
                </div>
                <div class="l2 folded">
                    <div class="doc_fields">
                        <div class="doc_header">
                            <div class="doc_number">DOC NUMBER</div>
                            <div class="supplier_id">SUPPLIER ID</div>
                            <div class="supplier_name">SUPPLIER NAME</div>
                            <div class="inv_count">INVOICE COUNT</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="doc_line">
                            <div class="doc_number">00000000</div>
                            <div class="supplier_id">0123456789</div>
                            <div class="supplier_name">XYZ XYZ</div>
                            <div class="inv_count">3</div>
                            <div class="inv_fields folded">
                                <div class="inv_main header">
                                    <div class="inv_id">INV_ID</div>
                                    <div class="inv_amount">INV AMOUNT</div>
                                    <div class="inv_curr">CURR</div>
                                    <div class="inv_amount_usd"></div>
                                    <div class="inv_owner"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="inv_line">
                                    <div class="inv_main">
                                        <div>000000001</div>
                                        <div>1000</div>
                                        <div>USD</div>
                                        <div>1000</div>
                                        <div>xyz</div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="inv_details folded">sth</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="inv_line">
                                    <div class="inv_main">
                                        <div>000000001</div>
                                        <div>1000</div>
                                        <div>USD</div>
                                        <div>1000</div>
                                        <div>xyz</div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="inv_details folded">sth</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="inv_line">
                                    <div class="inv_main">
                                        <div>000000002</div>
                                        <div>1000</div>
                                        <div>USD</div>
                                        <div>1000</div>
                                        <div>xyz</div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="inv_details folded">sth</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="inv_line">
                                    <div class="inv_main">
                                        <div>000000003</div>
                                        <div>1000</div>
                                        <div>USD</div>
                                        <div>1000</div>
                                        <div>xyz</div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="inv_details folded">sth</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="inv_line">
                                    <div class="inv_main">
                                        <div>000000004</div>
                                        <div>1000</div>
                                        <div>USD</div>
                                        <div>1000</div>
                                        <div>xyz</div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="inv_details folded">sth</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="l1">
                    <div class="id">002</div>
                    <div class="name">jkl</div>
                    <div class="status">active</div>
                    <div class="doc_count">3</div>    
                </div>
                <div class="l2 folded">
                    <div class="doc_fields">
                        <div class="doc_header">
                            <div class="doc_number">DOC NUMBER</div>
                            <div class="supplier_id">SUPPLIER ID</div>
                            <div class="supplier_name">SUPPLIER NAME</div>
                            <div class="inv_count">INVOICE COUNT</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="doc_line">
                            <div class="doc_number">00000000</div>
                            <div class="supplier_id">0123456789</div>
                            <div class="supplier_name">JKL JKL</div>
                            <div class="inv_count">3</div>
                            <div class="inv_fields folded">
                                <div class="inv_main header">
                                    <div class="inv_id">INV_ID</div>
                                    <div class="inv_amount">INV AMOUNT</div>
                                    <div class="inv_curr">CURR</div>
                                    <div class="inv_amount_usd"></div>
                                    <div class="inv_owner"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="inv_line">
                                    <div class="inv_main">
                                        <div>000000002</div>
                                        <div>2000</div>
                                        <div>USD</div>
                                        <div>2000</div>
                                        <div>jkl</div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="inv_details folded"></div>
                                </div>
                                
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
            $('.l1').on("click", (event) => {
                console.log($(event.target).parent().parent().find('.l2').toggleClass('folded'));
            })

            $('.doc_line').click(() => {
                console.log($(event.target).parent().find('.inv_fields').toggleClass('folded'));
                
            })
        </script>           
    </body>
</HTML>
```

I don't want to use display:none to avoid 'jumping' in table.

Is there any possibility to make transitions not delayed and also don't show unnecessary whitespace?

Comment: You can wrap the element you are trying to collapse in a div with no styling and collapse that instead. Your jumping issue has to do with padding/margin/etc causing it to have a non-zero height when collapsing

Comment: @VioletRosenzweig As 'jumping' I meant expanding/collapsing elements without transition.

So how exactly this wrapper should behave?